# Problem with passing argument to rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I am coding in Ruby 2.3.1p112 and Rails 4.2.7.1 and encounter this bug(?) when trying to use if-statement inside of one of the rake files.

I call this rake task:

```
task :bar, [:argument] => :environment do |_task, arg|
  binding.pry
  if arg.blank?
    # do stuff
  else
    # do other stuff
  end
end
```

from this worker:

```
 # ...
 def perform(location = nil)
    Rake::Task["foo:bar"].execute(location)
 end
 # ...
```

And when the code hits the binding.pry line I get the following issue:
[image: blank bug]

Is it a bug indeed or am I lacking some basic knowledge around here? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
arg[:argument].blank?
```

because `arg` is a hash with `:argument` key.

On a side note: the following would be more descriptive definition of a task (note plural `args` and `location` since it looks like you're passing location):

```
task :bar, [:location] => :environment do |_task, args|
  if args[:location].blank?
    # do stuff
  else
    # do other stuff
  end
end
```

Comment: that's exactly the line of code I was looking for! And thanks for editing the topic, I had problems with expressing myself :)

Comment: Hey! One more question - as I have made few steps ahead I encounter another issue - now when I pass an argument - say a string to a rake task I can no longer access args[:location], as args become that particular string. Any tips how to deal with this one?

Comment: @Rigi you have to do 2 things: first, pass anything to rake task and debug (with `binding.pry`) what `args` is; second: ensure you always pass a valid argument. Setup I showed should work, did you change it?

Comment: Hey! I did, when I invoke the rake task with the following line:
Rake::Task["foo:bar"].execute(location), then args seems to be "flatten" - I used binding.pry and typing args gives me value of location straight away.

But when I call it like:
Rake::Task["foo:bar"].execute, then I can use args[:location]
EDIT: I tried to use args.with_default but then I get "error: undefined method `with_defaults' for "London":String" (but this works ok when location is nil)

Comment: EDIT2: Thanks, problem's solved! In order to make sure the args will not get flatten I needed to call the rake task like:
Rake::Task["foo:bar"].execute(location: location) - so basically I just passed arg as hash :) Thanks once again!